# How to add a parameter to every function in an interface?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I've been running into an issue with proxying in typescript.
I'm using a module with a generic parameter, and I want to wrap calls to that API in my own API first, which should be pretty simple.
Programmatically, this has been fine, but the type system isn't the biggest fan of this.

Essentially the other module includes a method which can optionally accept a callback function, but leaves specifying this up to the generic type parameter it accepts.

This is what the relevant parts of the external module looks like:

```or-tag-here
interface ExternalAPI<T extends Record<string, any>>{
    // This function can take a callback funcion as the last parameter,
    // but is not specified in the type system
    // so it must be specified in T
    apiFunction<Key extends keyof T>(key: Key, ...others:Parameters<T[Key]>):void;
}
//Standard usage:
interface FunctionTypes {
    f(n:number, s:string):void
}
const apiInstance = new ExternalAPI<FunctionTypes>();
// Both are functional, but only the first is accepted by the type system
apiInstance.apiFunction('f', 3, "3") // works
apiInstance.apiFunction('f', 3, "3", console.log) // type error
```

Included below is a simplified snippet of my solution attempt; I wrapped the function types in another type which just adds a function parameter at the end of each of the declarations, and tried to use it in a proxy function, but this threw a type error:

```or-tag-here
type Func = (...args: any[]) => any

// Extracts only function keys
type FunctionMap<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Func ? T[Key] : never
}

// Adds a function parameter to any function
type WithCallback<F extends Func> =
    (...args: [...base: Parameters<F>, func: Func]) => any

// Adds a function parameter to all functions in a Record
type RecordWithCallback<T> = 
    {[Key in keyof T]:T[Key] extends Func? WithCallback<T[Key]>: never}



// Now suppose I want to proxy a call to the api, with a callback function
function proxyCallToAPI<T extends {}, Key extends keyof RecordWithCallback<T>>(
    // This should tell it to expect a callback function
    api: ExternalAPI<RecordWithCallback<T>>,
    key: Key,
    ...baseParameters:Parameters<FunctionMap<T>[Key]>
){
    /*
    Argument of type '[...Parameters<FunctionMap<T>[Key]>, () => void]' 
    is not assignable to parameter of type 
    'Parameters<RecordWithCallback<T>[Key]>'.ts(2345)
    */
    api.apiFunction(key,...baseParameters, ()=>{
        console.log('Success!')
    })
}
//Desired usage:
interface FunctionTypes {
    f(n:number, s:string):void
}
const apiInstance = new ExternalAPI<FunctionTypes>();
proxyCallToAPI('f', 3, "3") // should work
proxyCallToAPI('f', 3, "3", console.log) // should not work, the function parameter is unnecessary
```

This error doesn't make sense as, intuitively the parameters with a function at the end is *exactly* what 'Parameters<RecordWithCallback[Key]>' should be. Am I missing something here?

Is there another way to add a parameter to the end of all functions in an interface? Am I going about the proxying wrong somehow? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show an example of what a call to your proxy function would look like, compared to a call from the original API?

Comment: Ideally the call to the proxied API would look like a normal call to the base api, but with the callback passed in under the hood